# Язык C, многомерные массивы в структурах

Tags: c, массивы, struct

Хочу разобраться в следующем вопросе.

Помню, в каком-то источнике читал объяснения **Дениса Ритчи** о причинах, по которым был сделан выбор в пользу реализации хранения массива непосредственно в структуре, вместо того, чтобы хранить в структуре указатель на массив. Как он рассказывал, причины были в том, чтобы уменьшить потребление памяти, а так же предоставить возможность прямого присвоения между *объектами* структур одинакового типа.

В том источнике рассматривались лишь одномерные массивы, но не многомерные.

Вопросы такие:

1) В отношении упаковки многомерных массивов внутри структур действуют те же правила, что и для одномерных?

Например, равноценно ли это:

```
struct s
{
    int i;
    char m[2][2];
};
```

Этому?

```
struct s
{
    int i;
    char m00,
         m01,
         m10,
         m11;
};
```

2) Распространяется ли это на обычные массивы:

```
char m[2][4][8];
```

И каковы вообще правила адресации, если многомерный массив представлен в виде одномерного?

Поскольку я большую часть времени работаю с массивами в динамической памяти, то в моем представлении очень крепко устоялось представление о многомерном массиве в таком виде:

```
type **name;
```

3) Рассмотрим такой код:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int s_arr_2[SIZE][SIZE];

    int **d_arr_2 = malloc(sizeof(int*) * SIZE);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        d_arr_2[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
    }

    // Одинаковая запись, но по факту происходят совершенно разные вещи.
    s_arr_2[0][1] = 1;
    d_arr_2[0][1] = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Я **слишком** привык работать с динамическими массивами, в том числе с N-мерными. Я на автопилоте понимаю, что **d_arr_2** указывает на область памяти, с которой начинается массив указателей, и в этом массиве указателей хранятся адреса массивов типа **int**.

Когда же я вижу **s_arr_2**, то у меня возникают некоторые сложности с пониманием того, как происходит адресация, ведь в этом случае многомерный массив *на самом деле* является одномерным, и запись вида **s_arr_2[x][y]** переводится компилятором в нечто, что **явно и значительно** отличается от того, что получается при **d_arr_2[x][y]**.

Так что же происходит в случае **s_arr_2[x][y]**?

Comment: Что в вашем понимании "обычные массивы"? Массив это массив, указатель это указатель, бывают массивы указателей и указатель на (обычно) начало массива. Всё это нормально и ничего необычного в этом нет.

Comment: Я не знаю, как это объяснить, потому что с термином **статический** происходит много путаницы. Термин **автоматический** тоже не подходит, потому что не полностью отражает суть. Пожалуй, обычный массив в моем понимании - это массив, который создается компилятором, не важно, в теле функции или в глобальной области.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. с точки зрения расположения в памяти скорее всего да (для
   гарантии надо наверное сделать union).
2. многомерные массивы это
   лишь удобный способ навигации по одномерному массиву, на уровне
   представления в памяти разницы между многомерным и одномерным нет,
   если ваш вопрос об этом.

Что касается `char**` то к массивам, в общем случае, он никакого отношения не имеет.

Что касается последней части вашего вопроса, я добавил комментарии:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // создаём массив элементов типа int на стеке размером SIZE*SIZE 
    // при этом тип переменной s_arr_2 что-то вроде int*, значение -- адрес начала массива
    int s_arr_2[SIZE][SIZE];

    // создаём указатель на тип данных "указатель на int" (int*)
    // присваиваем ему адрес выделенной области памяти размером SIZE элементов типа int*
    int **d_arr_2 = malloc(sizeof(int*) * SIZE);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        // каждому элементу со смещением i присваиваем адрес выделенной памяти аналогично выше
        d_arr_2[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
    }

    // Одинаковая запись, но по факту происходят совершенно разные вещи.
    // Совершенно верно, потому что компилятор знает что это разные типы и обрабатывает их по разному!

    // это указатель на двумерный массив, его смещение считается как 0*SIZE+1
    s_arr_2[0][1] = 1;

    // это "просто" указатель, он отрабатывает в 2 этапа:
    // int* temp = d_arr_2[0]; -- получаем значение из адреса памяти со смещением 0
    // temp[1] - получаем значение из адреса памяти со смещением 1
    d_arr_2[0][1] = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Каковы правила адресации по многомерному массиву char m[2][7][4]?

Comment: char m[x] - массив из x элементов, каждый из которых имеет тип char. char m[x][y] - массив из x элементов, каждый из которых имеет тип char [y]. char m[x][y][z] - массив из x элементов, каждый из которых имеет тип char [y][z]...

Comment: Просто получается, что обращение m[1][2][3] = 1; Для массива, сгенерированного компилятором, и для массива, который был создан в куче, *под капотом* работает совсем по другому.

Comment: @Максим Мне кажется вы путаете операцию `[]` применённую к указателю и синтаксис объявления массивов, отсюда ваши затруднения.

Comment: Нет, я ничего не путаю, сейчас добавлю в вопрос описание того, что для меня оказывается странным.

Comment: @Максим дополнил ответ.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если массив многомерный, то в памяти распологается сначала 1 строка, потом вторая и тд.
имхо, нет смысла хранить в структуре указатель на массив, потому что полюбому же надо где-то хранить массив, так еще и указатель на него хранить, зачем?

Comment: Ну почему же, у этого вполне может быть смысл. С точки зрения языка нет разницы между "просто" указателем и "указателем на массив". На что он указывает решать исключительно вам.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin, соглашусь